# Chain rule notation when there is multivariables

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Use the chain rule to determinate $u_s$ and $u_t$.

$u = x \csc(yz)$

$x = rs$

$y = s^2 t$

z =  $\frac{s}{t^2}$

Determinating $u_s$ means applying the chain rule using $t$ as a constant? How would be the proccess?

Comment: What does $xcosec$ mean?

Comment: @MarkSaving fixed.

Comment: We have $\frac{\partial}{\partial s} u = \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial s} \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$. And similarly for $t$.

Comment: @MarkSaving then $u_s$ would be $r*csc(yz)-2stxz*ctg(yz)csc(yz)- 1/(t²)*xy*csc(yz)*ctg(yz)$?

Comment: @ShinYousoro: I suggest that you edit your post to incorporate the latest comment into your question, in order to show what work you have done on the question. This will help you avoid close votes and may attract good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
u_s&=x_s\csc(yz)+x\big(\csc(yz)\big)_s&\text{(product rule)}\\[1ex]
&=x_s\csc(yz)-x\csc(yz)\cot(yz)\big(yz\big)_s&\text{(chain rule)}\\[1ex]
&=x_s\csc(yz)-x\csc(yz)\cot(yz)(y_sz+yz_s)&\text{(product rule)}
\end{align}$$

The remaining derivatives are more immediate:

$$\begin{cases}x=rs\\y=s^2t\\z=\frac s{t^2}\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}x_s=r\\y_s=2st\\z_s=\frac1{t^2}\end{cases}$$

Then the ultimate result follows by substituting everything in $u$:

$$\begin{align}
u_s&=r\csc\left(\frac{s^3}t\right)-rs\csc\left(\frac{s^3}t\right)\cot\left(\frac{s^3}t\right)\left(\frac{2s^2}t+\frac{s^2}t\right)\\[1ex]
&=r\csc\left(\frac{s^3}t\right)-\frac{3rs^3}t\csc\left(\frac{s^3}t\right)\cot\left(\frac{s^3}t\right)
\end{align}$$

which agrees with the derivative you added in the comments, but the final result should be free of the intermediate dependent variables $x,y,z$.